# Is there an ASP MVC Equivalent for PHP's require_once()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering if there is an ASP.Net MVC equivalent to PHP's [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) function.

Lets say I need to call RenderAction to a particular action twice. However, inside the view that is rendered from said action, I need to print out some init scripts but only once.

Is there an easy mechanism to do this?
Should a flag be set in the controller and then passed into the view?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**Edit**
Thanks for the responses. I know I can do this through the controller or temp data or some mechanism like that but wasn't sure if there was anything built into .NET MVC that would have done this for me automatically.

Comment: I don't know enough about PHP, can you explain a little further? Maybe you could show us the code you have so far!

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Just click the link in the question!

Comment: @rock: The link the OP provided seems to explain it adequately.  It's about not including something like a CSS or Javascript file twice.

Comment: I get that, I'm just hoping for a little code context. Setting a flag seems like the best option. `ViewData["isSent"] = true/false;` and generating the link `if(ViewData["isSent"]){ //RenderAction}`

Comment: In this case, I'm rendering some HTML that will tie in with some facebook api calls. I need to call some javascript init scripts only once. However, if the view is rendered multiple times, I dont want to keep initing the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such equivalent.

> Should a flag be set in the controller and then passed into the view?

That seems like a good way. The flag needs to be passed as argument to the controller action when using the `RenderAction` helper.